# Allow an unprivileged user to start a webserver on port 80

Tags: sudo, root, webserver, privileges

**I understand the security implications of allowing a non-root user to start a webserver on ports 80 and 443.**

I would like to remove the privilege check to allow any non-root user to invoke a webserver on ports 80 and 443 on Ubuntu 16 and CentOS 7.

I have root access on the machine, but I need the webserver to be run as a different username to address NFS permission issues; this alternative username cannot have root access.

So far, I've looked at:

- `setcap cap_net_bind_service=ep /path/to/the/executable` (doesn't stick because the executable is recompiled remotely and stored on NFS)
- editing the `sudoers` file to enable passwordless `sudo` as the user from `root` (still has NFS access issues)

Ideally, I'd like something like setcap, but on the **ports**, rather than the executable, to drop the privilege check entirely.

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux

`authbind` looked promising, but it [doesn't seem to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/cqlpnq/cant_use_authbind_to_allow_binding_to_port_80/ewyluyh/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) with GoLang webservers

Ubuntu 16 is too old to allow changing the unprivileged port start range:

```
> sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=80
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What webserver?

Comment: It's a custom webserver written in GoLang, invoked with arguments in a tcsh script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I liked Stewart's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620524/105225), it adds yet another piece to the pipeline that can break (`systemd`), so I ended up using `capsh` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487053/1547214). I had to recompile it [from source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap.git/) to get the ambient capabilities feature (I stored the resulting binary as `/sbin/capsh2`), then I was able to set this as the launch command:

```
/sbin/capsh2 --keep=1 --user=nonrootuser --inh=cap_net_bind_service --addamb=cap_net_bind_service -- -c /path/to/webserver
```

When this command is run as root, the webserver correctly starts as `nonrootuser` and is able to bind to ports 80 and 443 in "userspace".

Answer (score 4):

I think `setcap` will be your answer.  I think the real question here is:  How will my system recognize when the webserver on the NFS has been touched so it can run a `setcap` command on it?

I think you'll want to set up an [`inotify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) or [`systemd.path`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) to monitor this webserver.  When that binary gets replaced, you'll detect it and trigger the `setcap` command that works for you.  This works especially well if your webserver runs via systemd already.

Here's an example with `systemd.path` assuming your server runs as systemd service `webserver.service`

```
# /etc/systemd/system/webcap.path
[Unit]
Description=Watching changes in the webserver binary
# Start monitoring only after the webserver is running.
After=webserver.service

[Path]
# Whenever someone writes to this path (binary is replaced), do something
PathModified=/path/to/webserver
# This is the service you launch when the above condition is met
Unit=webcap.service

[Install]
#Whenever the webserver is started, this monitor will also start
WantedBy=webserver.service
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/webcap.service
[Unit]
Description=Update caps of webserver

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=ssetcap cap_net_bind_service=ep /path/to/webserver
```

Comment: There was another answer to this question a moment ago.  It was radically different and involved wraping the auth layer.  I think the author deleted it.  I'd be interested to see it again or to understand why it was deleted.  It didn't look wrong, just different.

Comment: I agree, it had something to do with a setuid helper script?